# Button group/solo Center

Tags: html, css

I want to center this button on PC / Mobile as a container. I tried the following on CSS and HTML.

```html
<section id="jour">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
    <button class="btn1">Dimanche 13</button>
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
    <button class="btn1">Dimanche 13</button>
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What "button"? You have 5 buttons there. What should be centered and with respect to which container? Also, there is NO CSS in your code example, it should be there -- we need to know what you have tried.

Comment: did u delete what u post ? :o

Answer (score -1):

Is it suitable for your needs?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }
 
 .container2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 }
```

```html
<section id="jour">
  <h1>Space between buttons</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
    <button class="btn1">Dimanche 13</button>
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
    <button class="btn1">Dimanche 13</button>
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
  </div>
  <h1>Center aligned buttons</h1>
  <div class="container2">
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
    <button class="btn1">Dimanche 13</button>
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
    <button class="btn1">Dimanche 13</button>
    <button class="btn1">Jeudi 12</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: the seconde one look the on PC , but on phone cant see some button , do u think there is slution for it 
 as u see
https://gyazo.com/e0d0345e1af7f9de610fe8e13de43d29?token=654d23b322b66bc75edb6ec3b13f0c76

Comment: @ImadAnge, you're welcome. You can push these button into a fixed-width container and add overflow-y property into same div. I will update the answer for a responsive solution.